# PHP Добавление записей в БД

Tags: php

Есть php файл. Который по сути должен добавлять записи в базу по нажатию на кнопку. Но по нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит. С чем это может быть связано?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'vladiksan1998', 'JszwM4xj24Q') 
or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db('vladiksan1998') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных'); 
$fname = 'Вадим';
$sname = 'Олегович';
$score = '175';

if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `records` (`fname`, `sname`, 'score') 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['sname']."','".$_POST['score']."')");
    if ($sql) {

    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
}
?>
<table>
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ошибки какие-нибудь выдает? думаю проблема в запросе. У вас не приходит $_POST['fname'] нигде.

Comment: Нет. Консоль чистая

Answer (score 0):

Переделал код. Теперь работает.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";         
$dbuser = "vladiksan1998";       
$dbpassword = 'JszwM4xj24Q';   
$dbname = "vladiksan1998";         

$sname = "Анатолий";
$fname = "Толя";
$score = 15;

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
if (false === $link)
   die ('Error database connect<br>');
$select_result = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (false === $select_result)
   die ('Error database select</br>');
$query = "INSERT INTO records VALUES('$sname','$fname','$score')";
$query_result = mysql_query($query, $link);
if (false === $query_result)
   die ('Error database SQL query<br>');
$close_result = mysql_close($link);
if (false === $close_result)
   die ('Error database close<br>');
?>
```